# Css changed after inputting router-outlet

Tags: html, css, angular

I was developing a login screen within angular with the  within the `app.component.html` as such:

**app.component.ts**

```
<div class="container">
   <app-login></app-login>
</div>
```

and css as such:

**login.css**

```
.form-group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-group label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

**app.component.css**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}

app-login {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 274px;
  place-self: center;
}
```

However, since I have now incorporated routing into my app, I display the login page using the `<router-outlet>` component, but this has ruined the CSS of the login page is it once was...

**app.component.ts**

```
<div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I change my CSS files such that I can get back the look I once had?

Here is a **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-ruining-css?file=src/app/app.component.html)** to my example

**Update**
Solution found to the missing CSS (see below)

However now it appears  is hogging much of the screen, pushing my element downward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were targeting `<app-login>` in the app.component.css file and styling it to have a fixed width and align it center. What you have to remember is that, Angular enforces emulated view encapsulation and also when you are using router, `<app-login>` may be changed to some random dynamic name at run time thereby making your css classes that you might have written in app.component.css ineffective.

Its always a best practice to write styles for a component in its respective CSS file rather than the root components css file.

Here is a changed [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-ruining-css-ngl9ag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Here is the result: [image]

Comment: Your solution doesn't appear to work on my app which is based closely on the stackblitz example for some reason?

Comment: can you check if the stackBlitz i have provided in my answer is working as expected?

Comment: In the stackblitz it works, but I cannot recreate the solution in my own code.

Comment: well, i guess it boils down to the same thing as in the accepted answer, cannot help without looking at the code.

Comment: Ah I see now. I hadn't followed it to the letter, I apologise. Yes, this gets around the silly router-outlet hogging space at the top. Although I prefer @Suren's answer for it's simplicity in implementing a fix, yours is more accurate with holding css in each separate area.

Comment: the reason I wrote a separate answer instead of upvoting @Suren's answer is that, it is partially correct. Angular enforces Emulated View Encapsulation by default. If you change it to none as suggested in his answer, the local generic styling rules (ex: styling for elements like div, p etc) you write in a feature component's CSS file will be overridden by generic style rules (ex: styling for elements like div, p etc) written in root component's CSS file i.e. app.component.css. Not suggestable for a real world application.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @rgantla :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

on the `AppComponent` to allow styles to affect also those components which are used inside `AppComponent`.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent  {
   name = 'Angular';
}
```

But it will be better to use styles on those components for which they were declared.

This is a working [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-ruining-css-qsepqj).

Comment: Somebody downvoted it without posting their own solution? Lame.

Comment: However whenever I look now, it appears that the <router-outlet> is hogging space at the top of the screen? I will post a picture.

Comment: Can you see my issue?

Comment: I see the space, but it needs debuging to see what is in that place which I can't.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your answer. I will play and figure it out :-)